# No me toma el tipo char en una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario en PHP, le estoy indicando que cree la siguiente tabla:

```
$sql=" CREATE  TABLE auxtmp ( 
          n_linea     serial,
          c_concepto_mov char(2) not null,
          c_almacen_origen smallint default 0 not null,
          c_almacen_destino smallint default 0 not null,
          f_movimiento date not null,
          ca_movimiento decimal(19,3) not null,
          c_barra char(18) not null, 
          pr_compra decimal(10,2) default 0 not null, 
          pr_venta decimal(10,2) default 0 not null,
          nit_prov decimal(16,0) default 0 not null , 
          cs_factura char(20) not null ,
          foreign key (c_concepto_mov) references traslados(cod_trasl)
                      constraint noexiste_concepto$auxtmp,
          foreign key (c_almacen_origen) references m_almacenes(c_almacen)
                      constraint noexiste_almacen_origen$auxtmp,
          foreign key (c_almacen_destino) references m_almacenes(c_almacen)
                      constraint noexiste_almacen_destino$auxtmp,
          foreign key (c_barra) references read_plu(cod_barra)
                      constraint noexiste_Producto");
```

El campo `cs_factura` es tipo  `char`

Este formulario es para cargar un plano de un inventario, el cual tiene la siguiente estructura:

> Concepto | Alm_Origen | Alm_Destino |Fecha_Mov | Cantidad | Cod_Barra | Precio_Compra
>   Precio_Venta | Nit_Proveedor | Num_Factura

Cuando intento cargar un plano y el número de factura contiene letras, no me carga la información.

Este es uno de los INSERT que se realiza en el código:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $auxtmp $campos)VALUES($mireg) ";
```

Imprimiendo el SQL, ésta es la información que obtengo:

```
INSERT INTO auxtmp (c_concepto_mov, c_almacen_origen, c_almacen_destino,
                    f_movimiento, ca_movimiento, c_barra ,pr_compra,
                    pr_venta, nit_prov, cs_factura )
       VALUES('EC','3' ,'3' ,'18/05/2015' ,'104' ,'7703596011872',
              '24403' ,'24403' ,'165' ,'86ED3' )
```

Comment: Deberías incluir la parte del código que falla. Dices que la carga del plano es lo que no funciona, pero sólo pones cómo se crea la tabla. Añade todo el código relevante a la pregunta

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO $auxtmp $campos)VALUES($mireg) ";

Comment: Y el mensaje de error que obtienes es???

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuté tu código directo en mySql sin los constraints y funciona bien
puede haber un problema en las foreign keys.

una vez que ejecutes el insert muestra la respuesta del mySQL para que sepas que es lo que falla

```
echo mysql_error();
```

Answer (score 0):

El código tiene varios errores:

1. En la cadena `$sql`, no veo el sentido de usar `$auxtmp` al final de cada `constraint`
2. La construcción de la cadena termina **mal**, de este modo: `...constraint noexiste_Producto");`se cierra la comilla antes del paréntesis.
3. La definición del `CREATE TABLE` no es correcta para MySQL. Pongamos la `CONSTRAINT` **al principio** y veremos que pasa ... :) y también definamos que queremos nuestra base de datos en `MyIsam`... si es InnoDB lo de las claves variará ligeramente.
4. Aprovechemos para organizar un poco nuestro `CREATE TABLE`... da gusto un código organizado.
5. El `INSERT` tampoco es muy dichoso, los datos del tipo fecha deberían introducirse respetando el formato estándar que es: `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Veamos si funciona

---

#### Código: [`Ver DEMO (rextester)`](http://rextester.com/GELUY90089)

```
CREATE  TABLE auxtmp ( 
    n_linea           SERIAL,
    c_concepto_mov    char(2) not null,
    c_almacen_origen  smallint default 0 not null,
    c_almacen_destino smallint default 0 not null,
    f_movimiento      date not null,
    ca_movimiento     decimal(19,3) not null,
    c_barra           char(18) not null, 
    pr_compra         decimal(10,2) default 0 not null, 
    pr_venta          decimal(10,2) default 0 not null,
    nit_prov          decimal(16,0) default 0 not null , 
    cs_factura        char(20) not null ,


    CONSTRAINT   noexiste_concepto_auxtmp 
    FOREIGN KEY  (c_concepto_mov) 
    REFERENCES   traslados(cod_trasl),

    CONSTRAINT   noexiste_almacen_origen_auxtmp 
    FOREIGN KEY  (c_almacen_origen) 
    REFERENCES   m_almacenes(c_almacen),

    CONSTRAINT   noexiste_almacen_destino_auxtmp 
    FOREIGN KEY  (c_almacen_destino) 
    REFERENCES   m_almacenes(c_almacen),

    CONSTRAINT   noexiste_producto 
    FOREIGN KEY  (c_barra) 
    REFERENCES   read_plu(cod_barra)

                        ) ENGINE=MyIsam;


     INSERT INTO auxtmp 
        (c_concepto_mov, c_almacen_origen, c_almacen_destino,
         f_movimiento, ca_movimiento, c_barra ,pr_compra,
         pr_venta, nit_prov, cs_factura )

         VALUES('EC','3' ,'3' ,
                '2015-05-18' ,'104' ,'7703596011872', '24403' ,
                '24403' ,'165' ,'86ED3' ) ;


    SELECT * FROM auxtmp;
```

---

#### Resultado

```
n_linea c_concepto_mov  c_almacen_origen    c_almacen_destino   f_movimiento    ca_movimiento   c_barra         pr_compra   pr_venta    nit_prov    cs_factura
1       EC              3                   3                   18.05.2015      104,000         7703596011872   24403,00    24403,00    165         86ED3
```